# Trying to get a positive or negative number in Parse TimeSpan VB

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on a project that i received some great help from users here before.  I am trying to subtract times that are formatted in a String.

Here is the code that i am using that works like a champ with one exception.  It does not matter if i subtract value2 from value1 or value1 from value2 the answer is always the same.  I am looking to have it provide me with a negative number if the value being subtracted is greater than the number being subtracted from.

```
Dim cell2Value = "08:01:05.900" 'dgvConvert(3, 1).Value.ToString
Dim cell1Value = "08:01:50.000" 'dgvConvert(3, 2).Value.ToString

Dim value2 = TimeSpan.Parse(cell2Value)
Dim value1 = TimeSpan.Parse(cell1Value)

TextBox1.Text = (value2 - value1).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
```

Comment: Use `Dim answer = (value2 - value1)` and look at it in debug you'll see it is a negative value

Comment: Your String format has no field for negatives, but one is available for you to use, e.g. `[-][d:]h:mm:ss[.FFFFFFF]`. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx for a full explanation.

Comment: To clarify, the negative sign isnt allowed as part of a custom format, but is part of the "c" format: `answer.ToString("c")` == `-00:00:44.1000000`

Comment: I do not see that i can select your answer but if you answer it then i will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a check to see if the you have a negative time, and then pick a different format.

```
    Dim cell2Value As String = "08:01:05.100" 'dgvConvert(3, 1).Value.ToString
    Dim cell1Value As String = "08:01:55.123" 'dgvConvert(3, 2).Value.ToString

    Dim value2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(cell2Value)
    Dim value1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(cell1Value)

    Dim diff As TimeSpan = value2 - value1

    Dim s As String = If(diff.TotalMilliseconds >= 0, diff.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"), diff.ToString("\-hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"))
```

Comment: That is exactly what i am going to do except using a < "00:00:00.000" as a comparison.  Thanks!

Comment: @ParkerO'Connel - you don't mean a string comparison do you?  I hope not.  Think it through before you do.

Comment: Yup, just wasted about 30 min but still learning.  I am going to try using your code to do a comparison or give an attempt at looking for if the string starts with a "-" and then use that.  Will post back after i try to work through it.  Thanks!